# Reactive Cocoa and multiple AFNetworking requests in short period of time

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, reactive-cocoa

I'm struggeling with the way I handle multiple requests to a web service with AFNetworking and Reactive Cocoa. In this scenario the user is asking the API to deliver a bunch of suggestions for a character/integer search input to pick a city out of a list.

Here's my code:

First the method that gets executed as soon as the user types in more than 3 characters/integers

```
- (void)fetchData:(NSString *)searchText
{
    NSLog(@"%@", searchText);

    if ([searchText validateStringwithPattern:BKPostcodeRegEx]) {
        self.searchURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@location/postalCode/%@/%@", BKBaseURL, self.countryCode, searchText];
    } else if ([searchText validateStringwithPattern:BKCityRegEx]) {
        self.searchURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@location/city/%@/%@", BKBaseURL, self.countryCode, searchText];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error Alert - No Valid Input");
        return;
    }

    RAC(self, searchResults) = [[[self postRequest] map:^(NSDictionary *json) {
        NSArray *results = json[@"data"][@"locations"];
        return results;
    }] catch:^(NSError *error) {
        return [RACSignal return:@[]];
    }];
}
```

Now this is where I actually create the signal and pass it back to `self.searchResults`:

```
- (RACSignal *)postRequest
{
    return [[[RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {

        [self.requestOperationManager GET:self.searchURL parameters:self.params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            [subscriber sendNext:responseObject];
            [subscriber sendCompleted];
        }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            [subscriber sendError:error];
        }];

        return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
            [self.requestOperationManager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
        }];

    }] doError:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error description]);
    }] throttle:0.5];
}
```

I think the problem is, that I start subscribing to the signal before the signal prior to the current signal has been completed and thus cause an exception as I'm trying to subscribe again.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Signal  name: [[[[+createSignal:] -doError:] -throttle: 0.500000]
>   -map:] -catch: is already bound to key path "searchResults" on object , adding signal
>    name: [[[[+createSignal:] -doError:]
>   -throttle: 0.500000] -map:] -catch: is undefined behavior'

My guess is that I have to try something like this in the postRequest method but this doesn't seem to work out of the box:

```
if (self.requestOperationManager.operationQueue.operationCount == 1) {
  NSLog(@"cancel all operations");
  [self.requestOperationManager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
  [subscriber sendCompleted];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only call `RAC()` once on any given object's key path. It looks like `-fetchData:` can be called more than once, which will result in `RAC()` being called multiple times on the same object and key path.

Typically, you call `RAC()` in some sort of setup method (such as an initializer or `-[UIViewController loadView]`) so that it only gets called once. Instead of waiting until the user types more than 3 characters and then calling `-fetchData:`, think about how you could create a signal that sends a value when the user types more than 3 characters, and assign that signal to the `RAC()`'d property. For example (completely untested):

```
- (void)someInitializationMethod
{
    RACSignal *moreThan3 = [[myTextField rac_textSignal] filter:^(NSString *text) {
        return [text length] > 2;
    }];

    RAC(self, searchResults) = [self rac_liftSelector:@selector(fetchData:) withSignals:moreThan3];
}

- (void)fetchData:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if ([searchText validateStringwithPattern:BKPostcodeRegEx]) {
        // ... etc ...
    }

    return [[[self postRequest] map:^(NSDictionary *json) {
        NSArray *results = json[@"data"][@"locations"];
        return results;
    }] catch:^(NSError *error) {
        return [RACSignal return:@[]];
    }];
}

- (RACSignal *)postRequest
{
    // ... etc ...
```